Protect routes with user has roles
I want to protect my routes in reactjs  and i have users with roles so please show me how to do it in home page i have login with checkbox for roles Student And Teacher and i have this routes please show me the best method to do it this is my routes.
const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Firstpage></Firstpage>,
    },

   
    {
        path: "/Student",
        
          element: <Studenpage />,
          children: [

            { path: "",
             element: <Main /> 
            },{
              path: "form",
              element: < Pfeextern/>,
            },
            {
              path: "upload",
              element: <Uploadfile />,
            },
            {
              path: "propose",
              element: <Propose />,
            }
          ],                     
    },

        {
          path: "/teacher",
          
            element:<HomePageEncadreur />,
            children: [
              { path: "",
               element: <Mainn/> 
              },{
                path: "Request",
                element: < Request/>,
              },
              
            ],
            
            
           
          },
    
    
      {
        path: "/loginAdmin",
        element: <LoginAdmin />, // Render LoginAdmin component initially
      },
          {
            path: '/Admin', // Default child route
            element: <Adminnn />, // Render Adminnn component after successful login
            children: [
              {
                path: "",
                element: <Students />, // Render nested route within Adminnn component
              },
              {
                path: "team",
                element: <Teacher />, // Render nested route within Adminnn component
              },
              {
                path: "jury",
                element: <Jury />, // Render nested route within Adminnn component
              },
              {
                path: "form",
                element: <Form />, // Render nested route within Adminnn component
              },
              {
                path: "feedback",
                element: <Feedback />, // Render nested route within Adminnn component
              },
          
              {
                path: "calendar",
                element: <Calendar />, // Render nested route within Adminnn component
              },
            ],
          },
        ],`
  );


  return (
    <>
      {routes}
    </>
  );


I did the above but its not working properly. Can I use context to check roles?

If I get this right, you already tried to used context or any other way to protect your routes against the roles. However, in the above block of code, you demonstrate nothing related to protecting the routes.. Just the routes themselves. Can you give more insights on what is done and how its failing?

Petros i want to apply it to this routes and i dont know how

I would take a different approach to this. I would use the RouteProvider alongside with createBrowserRouter and createRoutesFromElements.
This would give the opportunity to pass in a routes configuration object along with the roles that every route should have in order to be visible.
So my app.tsx would be something like:
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Firstpage></Firstpage>,
  },
  {
    path: "/Student",
    roles: ["Student"],
    element: <Studenpage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <Main />,
      },
      {
        path: "form",
        element: <Pfeextern />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/Teacher",
    roles: ["Teacher"],
    element: <TeacherPage />,
  },
];

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(buildRoutes(routes))
);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

root.render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);


then my buildRoutes function would be something like this:
export const buildRoutes = (routes: RouteObject): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <Route path={routes.path} element={routes.element}>
            {routes.children?.map((route: RouteObject) => buildRoute(route))}
        </Route>
    )
}

and my buildRoute function like this:
export const buildRoute = (route: RouteObject) => {
    const {path, roles, element, children, ...rest} = route

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            key={`${path}_key`}
            path={path}
            element={
                <ProtectedRoute roles={roles}>
                  {route.element}
                </ProtectedRoute>
            }
        >
            {(children as any)?.map((childRoute: any) => buildRoute(childRoute))}
        </Route>
    )
}

and finally ProtectedRoute.tsx:
export interface ProtectedRouteProps{
    roles: string[]
    children?: ReactElement<any, any>[] | ReactElement<any, any>

}

export const ProtectedRoute = (props: ProtectedRouteProps) => {
    
    const effectiveRoles: string[] = [] //get from token or context
    
    const roleExists = (roles: string[]) => {
        return roles.some(role => effectiveRoles.includes(role))
    }
    
    return roleExists(props.roles) ? props.children : <Navigate to="/unauthorized" />
}

I hope these help to get you going
